# ElasticSearch provides different TF-IDF scores within a same index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, opensearch

I'm currently trying to setup a combined query made of several match fuzzy queries. I noticed something I'd like to have an explanation for before I move to combining queries.
I have documents indexed such as the following in a single index `text`:

```json
{
    "article": "someArticleName",
    "articleInfo": "someInfo", // potentially missing if this matters
    "userId": 2
}
```

If I run the following query:

```json
{
    "from":0,
    "min_score":0.6,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"term":{"userId":{"value": 2}}}
            ],
            "should": {"match":{"article":{"fuzziness":"AUTO","query":"1705aa"}}}
        }
    },
    "size":20,
    "sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}],
    "explain": True
}
```

then I receive this as result:

```json
{'took': 16,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 6, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 3.5664783,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'text',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'id-1',
    '_score': 3.5664783,
    '_source': {'id': 'id-1',
     'article': '1705aa',
     'indexName': 'text',
     'currentVersion': 0,
     'userId': 2,
     'indexedUtc': '2022-05-23T07:47:48.6175402+00:00'}},
   {'_index': 'text',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'id-2',
    '_score': 1.3915253,
    '_source': {'id': 'id-2',
     'article': '1705aa',
     'articleInfo': 'someInfo',
     'userId': 2,
     'indexedUtc': '2022-05-23T09:57:11.8080429+00:00'}},
   ...
}
```

and this as an explanation:

```json
{'description': 'sum of:',
 'details': [{'description': 'weight(article:1705aa in 220) '
                             '[PerFieldSimilarity], result of:',
              'details': [{'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost '
                                          '* idf * tf from:',
                           'details': [{'description': 'boost',
                                        'details': [],
                                        'value': 2.2},
                                       {'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 '
                                                       '+ (N - n + 0.5) / (n + '
                                                       '0.5)) from:',
                                        'details': [{'description': 'n, number '
                                                                    'of '
                                                                    'documents '
                                                                    'containing '
                                                                    'term',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1},
                                                    {'description': 'N, total '
                                                                    'number of '
                                                                    'documents '
                                                                    'with '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 37}],
                                        'value': 3.232121},
                                       {'description': 'tf, computed as freq / '
                                                       '(freq + k1 * (1 - b + '
                                                       'b * dl / avgdl)) from:',
                                        'details': [{'description': 'freq, '
                                                                    'occurrences '
                                                                    'of term '
                                                                    'within '
                                                                    'document',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.0},
                                                    {'description': 'k1, term '
                                                                    'saturation '
                                                                    'parameter',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.2},
                                                    {'description': 'b, length '
                                                                    'normalization '
                                                                    'parameter',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 0.75},
                                                    {'description': 'dl, '
                                                                    'length of '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.0},
                                                    {'description': 'avgdl, '
                                                                    'average '
                                                                    'length of '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.2972972}],
                                        'value': 0.50156736}],
                           'value': 3.5664783}],
              'value': 3.5664783},
             {'description': 'match on required clause, product of:',
              'details': [{'description': '# clause',
                           'details': [],
                           'value': 0.0},
                          {'description': 'userId:[2 TO 2]',
                           'details': [],
                           'value': 1.0}],
              'value': 0.0}],
 'value': 3.5664783}
{'currentVersion': 0,
 'id': 'id-1',
 'indexName': 'text',
 'indexedUtc': '2022-05-23T07:47:48.6175402+00:00',
 'article': '1705aa',
 'userId': 2}
{'description': 'sum of:',
 'details': [{'description': 'weight(article:1705aa in 0) '
                             '[PerFieldSimilarity], result of:',
              'details': [{'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost '
                                          '* idf * tf from:',
                           'details': [{'description': 'boost',
                                        'details': [],
                                        'value': 2.2},
                                       {'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 '
                                                       '+ (N - n + 0.5) / (n + '
                                                       '0.5)) from:',
                                        'details': [{'description': 'n, number '
                                                                    'of '
                                                                    'documents '
                                                                    'containing '
                                                                    'term',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 5},
                                                    {'description': 'N, total '
                                                                    'number of '
                                                                    'documents '
                                                                    'with '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 20}],
                                        'value': 1.3397744},
                                       {'description': 'tf, computed as freq / '
                                                       '(freq + k1 * (1 - b + '
                                                       'b * dl / avgdl)) from:',
                                        'details': [{'description': 'freq, '
                                                                    'occurrences '
                                                                    'of term '
                                                                    'within '
                                                                    'document',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.0},
                                                    {'description': 'k1, term '
                                                                    'saturation '
                                                                    'parameter',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.2},
                                                    {'description': 'b, length '
                                                                    'normalization '
                                                                    'parameter',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 0.75},
                                                    {'description': 'dl, '
                                                                    'length of '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.0},
                                                    {'description': 'avgdl, '
                                                                    'average '
                                                                    'length of '
                                                                    'field',
                                                     'details': [],
                                                     'value': 1.1}],
                                        'value': 0.472103}],
                           'value': 1.3915253}],
              'value': 1.3915253},
             {'description': 'match on required clause, product of:',
              'details': [{'description': '# clause',
                           'details': [],
                           'value': 0.0},
                          {'description': 'userId:[2 TO 2]',
                           'details': [],
                           'value': 1.0}],
              'value': 0.0}],
 'value': 1.3915253}
{'currentVersion': 0,
 'id': 'id-2',
 'indexName': 'text',
 'indexedUtc': '2022-05-23T09:57:11.8080429+00:00',
 'article': ' 1705aa ',
 'articleInfo': 'someInfo'
 'userId': 2}
```

Why do I get a score of `3.5664783` for the first document and `1.3915253` for the second?
They're located in the same index and are both an exact match of the fuzzy query. Number of documents used in `_explanation` seem different and I don't understand why and how to get equal scores for both documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response shows that you have 5 shards.
Shards impact the relevance scoring. Your documents will be distributed among your shards and  by default, Elasticsearch makes each shard responsible for producing its own scores.
Hence, the number of documents used in the explanation is different for both the results.

Read more about impact of shards on scoring [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html)

By default, Elasticsearch will use a search type called **Query Then Fetch**. The way it works is as follows:

1. Send the query to each shard
2. Find all matching documents and calculate scores using local Term/Document
   Frequencies
3. Build a priority queue of results (sort, pagination with from/to, etc)
4. Return metadata about the results to requesting node. Note, the actual document
   is not sent yet, just the scores
5. Scores from all the shards are merged and sorted on the requesting node, docs are
   selected according to query criteria
6. Finally, the actual docs are retrieved from individual shards where they reside.
   Results are returned to the client

To get more consistent score you can use **DFS Query Then Fetch** with your search query like this

```
GET /test_index/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
```

It does the following:

1. Prequery each shard asking about Term and Document frequencies
2. Send the query to each shard
3. Find all matching documents and calculate scores using global Term/Document
   Frequencies calculated from the prequery.
4. Build a priority queue of results (sort, pagination with from/to, etc)
5. Return metadata about the results to requesting node. Note, the actual document
   is not sent yet, just the scores
6. Scores from all the shards are merged and sorted on the requesting node, docs are
   selected according to query criteria
7. Finally, the actual docs are retrieved from individual shards where they reside.
   Results are returned to the client

Comment: I went with routing but this answer gave me the explanation, thanks!